# Laravel 5.0 phpunit models

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

I have clean install of Laravel 5.0, and I have issues with phpunit tests.
If I create a test for user model, I'm getting error - User class not found.

If I test controllers, works fine, controller classes are detected.

As a temporary workaround, just to test if it is working, I added class User inside UserTest.php.

I tried to add folder models in app folder, placing the class inside, similar as it was in Laravel 4.2, changed composer.json as well, ran composer dump-autoload, but it didn't work.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/model"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
    }
},
```

The simple classes looks like this:

```
// tests/models/UserTest.php

class UserTest extends TestCase
{

    protected $user;


    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testEmptyNameFailExpected()
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->name = '';
        $result = $user->isValid();
        $this->assertFalse($result);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

And here is User.php class in app folder (in laravel 5.0 the architecture is different)

```
// app/User.php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
    public static $rules = [ 'name' => 'required|min:3'  ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];


    /**
     * validate input
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isValid()
    {
        $validation = Validator::make($this->attributes, static ::$rules);
        if ($validation->passes()) return true;
        $this->errors = $validation->messages();

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try using the FQN for the model. In your case it may be `App\User`

Comment: I tried, but still was not recognized. It searches for the class inside tests folder, so I supposed that something with autoloading is not good

Comment: @davidxd33 today this worked, not sure why yesterday didn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed two problems with your code:

You said your test folder is

```
app/tests/models/UserTest.php
```

That is incorrect. In a clean install of Laravel 5.0 - the test class is in the base folder - not the `app` folder - so it should be

```
tests/models/UserTest.php
```

Also - your User is namespaced in Laravel 5.0 - so your code will need to be

```
$user = new \App\User;
```

Comment: for first problem - it is a typo, I set it up in tests folder, sorry. For second, thanks, today morning I make it work. Weird, as I tried the same thing yesterday and didn't work at all.